# Use ui-view as the template for state inside ui-router instead of an external template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app that is currently using the angular **ui-router** module dependency. The only aspect of the ui-router that I'm currently employing is the ability to apply/modify $stateParams to $scope and vice versa so the URL can change the way data is displayed in the controller to a user on arrival **(i.e. url?param=something will filter the data by something)**.

I have the following in my app.config to set the state:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: '/?param',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      controller: 'listController',
      params: {
        param: {
            value: 'something',
            squash: true
        }
      }
    });
```

On my homepage, template.html successfully loads when the app is instantiated as such:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I have reached a roadblock and realize that calling the template from within **templateUrl** isn't going to work, as this app is being built inside another framework and therefore needs to be called from within the homepage itself to access its full capabilities.

Being a noob at AngualrJS, I was wondering if anyone can tell me what the best way is to accomplish this while still keeping the logic of **$stateParams** and other **ui-router** capabilities intact for the future.

For instance, could I just remove the **templateUrl** parameter from my state and call the controller directly inside the **ui-view** like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ui-view>
    <div ng-controller="listController">
        do something
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I also looked into changing the entire logic from using **ui-router** to simply using the **$location** service but I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this without needing to over-do everything.

Comment: Could you supply the folder hierarchy? `templateUrl` should work **unless** the template is placed above the `index.html` file in the hierarchy.

Comment: It's not that templateUrl doesn't work. It works fine. It just limits the app's ability to access functions and other utilities available from within the framework since templateUrl behaves as a static file. I can load the framework's dependencies from within the templateUrl file but that makes everything loads twice (since index.html and template.html both need these dependencies to work properly).

Comment: Which framework are we talking about?

Comment: Wordpress + the Genesis framework